# how to query differently-structured files?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

**Is it possible to execute a query against files that have different schemas?**

I have 2 sets of files in the same directory. The second type has an extra field.

**Type 1**

```
id, first, last
1, liza, smith
```

**Type 2**

```
id, first, last, state
4, alex, gordon, CT
```

**Desired Result**

```
1, liza
4, alex
```

**How do we query files with different schemas, but where you want the same output fields?**

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT id, first                
FROM "/one 1300/{files}.csv"
USING Extractors.Csv();

@interestingRows = SELECT id, first FROM  @interestingRows;

OUTPUT @interestingRows
TO @uriPrefix + "/one 1300/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

Comment: if you select the fileds with an ```?``` you will import the two types and if one of the types will not have the state value it will come as null. This works for the physical files, don't know about schema

Comment: @Praetorian1995 an example would be very helpful

Comment: Forget it, assuming your state columns is a string, it can not be nullable. I will post as answer the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about importing the column as one using a delimiter you know does not exist in the data, then splitting it afterwards using the `Split` method of the string class?  Something like this:

```
@working =
    EXTRACT wholeRow  string
    FROM "/one 1300/{*}.csv"
    USING Extractors.Text(delimiter:'|');


@working =
    SELECT 
        wholeRow.Split(',')[0] AS id,
        wholeRow.Split(',')[1] AS first,
        wholeRow.Split(',')[2] AS last
    FROM @working;


OUTPUT @working
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```

Comment: this is a beautiful solution, thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

The CSV outputter not solve your problem.
You will need a custom extractor to solve this.
I recommend you to use Flexible Extractor

check this:

https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/FlexibleSchemaExtractor

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrys/2016/08/15/how-to-deal-with-files-containing-rows-with-different-column-counts-in-u-sql-introducing-a-flexible-schema-extractor/

The other solutions is to extract data with diferent schema separatly

Answer (score 1):

Since you said that this two types are actualy in the same file, assuming that they are like this:

[image: data]

You just extract it with all the columns and set quoting to false:

```cs
//Extract the data
@extractedData =
    EXTRACT id int,
            first string,
            last string,
            state string
    FROM "data.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv(skipFirstNRows : 1, quoting: false);
```

Then you just select the fields you need and output them:

```cs
//Select the fields
@finalData = SELECT id, first FROM @extractedData;

//Output the data
OUTPUT @finalData 
    TO "/Desired Result.csv"
    USING Outputters.Csv(quoting: false);
```

The desired result:

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: very nice however type1 and type2 records are mixed together in the same file right now

Comment: So how is your file then? Like this?  id, first, last, state | 1, liza, smith | 4, alex, gordon, CT

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' did it help? I can't know since you din't mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: no that will not work https://drive.google.com/uc?id=10sEdwHjSAfMz3CDlvBLz1x1rZ3RHuKd6

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' if your data is structured as ahead it works, you should check your data.

Comment: the source data `1, liza, smith` shows that there's no `,` after `smith`. therefore this record shows 3 fields, whereas the other record is 4 fields

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' obviously in this case you need to do some ETL cleaning and convert your data to a uniform structure.

Comment: or use a custom extractor?

Comment: The custom extractor will be more efficient if the amount of data is not huge. In my experience, the custom extractor is not optimized for huge amount of that, but it's up to you to decide if you can do it or not...